# Send IQueryable of class object from view to controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have getting error on return IQuerable object from view to controller in MVC Application

[image]

```
public partial class Course_Services
{
    #region Process All Courses Application's URL
    public IQueryable<CourseInstanceModel> ProcessAllCoursesApplicationURL(CourseApplicationsURLFeed_Model _obj)
    {
        IQueryable<CourseInstanceModel> ListOfCoursesInstances; 

        //get all the courses which have Application URL is Null..
        using(var _uof = new Courses_UnitOfWork())
        {
            ListOfCoursesInstances = _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll();

          var _listOfCoursesWithoutURL = from b in ListOfCoursesInstances 
                                           where b.ApplicationURL == null
                                           select ListOfCoursesInstances;

          return _listOfCoursesWithoutURL;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I am struggling to understand where I am doing mistake. Many thanks in advance

Comment: `return ListOfCoursesInstances.Where(x => x.ApplicationURL == null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting the wrong thing. You should be selecting the `b` variable that you've created there.

```
var _listOfCoursesWithoutURL = from b in ListOfCoursesInstances 
                               where b.ApplicationURL == null
                               select b;
```

The way you have it now you're having it select the `ListOfCoursesInstances` once for every single element in that List. Since `ListOfCourseInstances` is itself an `IQueryable<CourseInstanceModel>`, that means that you are returning an `IQueryable<IQueryable<CourseInstanceModel>>`, which is invalid for the method that you have, which only returns `IQueryable<CourseInstanceModel>`.

Alternatively, you could also do what @Steve wrote in the comments, namely:

```
return ListOfCoursesInstances.Where(x => x.ApplicationURL == null);
```

This uses LINQ's Extension Methods instead of the regular syntax to do the same thing. It's just a matter of personal preference at that point.

Comment: so what you are saying that I cannot return data in IQueryable to controller method???

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying at all. I'm saying that your LINQ query is not giving back your return type the way you have it set up. The code I've written above should fix that problem.

Comment: I have IDispose error come in controller, so I change to list return which worked... I am wondering if I ever can pass IQuerable after DbContext close.. I Have feeling answer is no but just getting exert advice

Comment: Not the way you want it, no. Unless something happens to make it execute immediately (like `.ToList()`), it will give the error in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ListOfCoursesInstances
```

You just returned the entire source collection for every element in your `select` clause.

As the error is trying to tell you, this gives a collection of collections, which is not what you want.

You probably want to select the original item (`b`)

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Course_Services
{
    #region Process All Courses Application's URL
    public List<CourseInstanceModel> ProcessAllCoursesApplicationURL(CourseApplicationsURLFeed_Model _obj)
    {

        //get all the courses which have Application URL is Null..
        using(var _uof = new Courses_UnitOfWork())
        {
          var  ListOfCoursesInstances = _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll();

          var _listOfCoursesWithoutURL = (from b in ListOfCoursesInstances 
                                           where b.ApplicationURL == null
                                           select b).ToList();


          return _listOfCoursesWithoutURL;
        }

    }
    #endregion
}
```